# Socket Over Non-Internet Access Point

Tags: access-point, sockets

I want to use a Raspberry Pi as an access point that is not linked to the internet. If I connected one other device to that access point, how could I connect a socket between this access point and the device connected to it.
If this is not possible with sockets, how else could I transfer data in this way?

[image]

Comment: The same way you would create any socket!

Comment: That's what I would think, but the Raspberry Pi is not connected to any network. UNLESS, you can connect the Raspi to its OWN network. 

Comment: can you ping the connected device?

Comment: Are you asking two questions? How to configure an access point and then program a unix socket connection to it? Or do you have already a running access point? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "***pi-ap***"- a Github repo which automates the configuration of a Pi into an AP- and unplug the uplink from your Pi from the router to ensure it can't route traffic to/from the Internet.

https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap/

So you'd connect to the AP on the `WLAN0` IP- the default for "***pi-ap***" is 192.168.0.1- by joining the SSID you set for your "***pi-ap***" installation.  Once you join the AP, you can SSH into it on that IP.

"***pi-ap***" should meet your requirements to create an AP with not Internet connectivity with minimal effort. Seriously, edit a few variables in `variables.sh` and then do `sudo ./install.sh` and you've got yourself an AP.  HTH-  Terrence